# DNS custom local network

Tags: dns

I have a small single-board computer running armbian and set up as an AP with Network Manager. This board is also hosting a HTTP server allowing me to run a website from it on my local network.

I would like to access this network using a custom domain like `mylocalwebsite.com`.

This is only supposed to be available on the LAN.

I guess I would need to install and configure a DNS server like Bind9. Or is there a way to handle this with Network Manager/dnsmasq?

Thank you for your help in guiding me with the more straight forward solution in order to avoid me to go with an over complicated solution or losing time on a dead end.

Comment: I'd say Bind9 is overkill for local DNS - I use Unbound for this purpose, which is pretty lightweight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually the resolv.conf was not working as it was always replace at boot by NetworkManger.

the key was to create a file in /etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq-shared.d  with the following info:

```
address=/MyCustomLocalDomain/10.0.x.x
```

after reboot, the DNS should work properly

Answer (score 0):

You can use both bind9 or dnsmasq, they both offer DNS services that would do what you are looking to do. Which one to use is up to you, but if you want the simplest option, dnsmasq might be a better choice.

One of the advantages of dnsmasq (from a simplicity perspective) is that its default configuration is to use your system's default DNS (`/etc/resolv.conf`), so it will pretty much work out of the box.